# Show/hide different custom tabs, individually

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have my custom Ribbon tabs and I want to show or hide some of them upon given event. But I want to show/hide them individually, so the tabs should not be dependent on each other or anything like that.

I've been trying the examples from this [documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633442%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390805%28v=office.11%29.aspx) but no success.

This is the ribbon XML for the tabs:

```
<tab id="t1" label="CustomTab" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="xtab">
      <!-- some other elements -->
</tab>
<tab id="t2" label="CustomTab_2" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="xtab_2">
   <!-- some other elements -->
</tab>
```

and the VB code:

```
Private isVisible As Boolean = False

Public Sub GetVisible(control As Office.IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal As Boolean)
   returnedVal = isVisible
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String)
   ribbon.Invalidate()
End Sub

    Public Sub show_xtab(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
        isVisible = True
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="xtab")
    End Sub

    Public Sub hide_xtab(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
        isVisible = False
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="xtab")
    End Sub
```

Here I'm trying just with one of them, to make at least that one to work (and then I'm gonna take care of passing the Tag attribute dynamically). But this does not work.

However, if I change the `GetVisible` method to the following:

```
Public Function GetVisible(control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Return isVisible
End Function
```

it will work, but both of the tabs simultaneously. And I want to control them separately.

Any suggestions or tutorials ?

**Update: tried some solution from suggestions from comments**

XML is still the same. VB code:

```
Public MyTag as String

Sub GetVisible(control As Office.IRibbonControl, ByRef visible As Boolean)
    If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
        visible = True
    Else
        visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String)
    MyTag = Tag
    ribbon.Invalidate()
End Sub

Public Sub show_xtab(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="xtab")
End Sub

Public Sub show_xtab_2(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="xtab_2")
End Sub
```

but still no success...

Comment: Have you seen [This](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm) There is a workbook which you can download

Comment: It is the same as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633442%28v=office.11%29.aspx And he provides only the XML, without the VB code.

Comment: Did you click on `Download the example workbooks`

Comment: Yes, ofc. It only contains 6 Excel files with explanations and XML code, but no VB.

Comment: Which file did you check? "Hide Tab"? The VB Code is there

Comment: Oh, I had to go to the VBA Editor (Alt+F11). Okay, I am gonna check it out now. :)

Comment: If you remove "As Boolean" from the GetVisible callback signature it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it seems pretty stupid and I don't know why it works like that, but the solution is the following - I just changed `GetVisible` from `Sub` to `Function` and removed the `visible` argument, so I directly return `True` or `False`, like this:

```
Public Function GetVisible(control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct callback signature procedure type is Sub and If you remove "As Boolean" from the GetVisible callback signature it works as expected.

Signatures here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN